# Pydev installation problem in eclipse

Tags: python, java, eclipse

I am trying to install pydev 5.0 in eclipse 3.8.1 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS,using  Help->install new software.. I have Open java 1.7.0_101 and python 2.7.6. Installation success but it doesn't see in preference,  but it seen in Eclipse installation details. I have tried some solution over Internet, But nothing work for me. somebody Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pydev 5.0 requires Java 8 as mentioned on their [home page](http://www.pydev.org/). Version 4.5.5 is the last release to support Java 7.

Comment: thanks **greg-449** . Installed java8  (http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/install-openjdk-8-ubuntu-14-04-12-04-lts/) and downloaded eclipse neon from (https://www.eclipse.org) . Now its works fine.